# Prevent element occuring at beginning or end of line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which contains a number of tag elements. There is another element between each tag that contains a pipe symbol as a seperator. The number of tags in the containing div is dynamic.

Occasionally, there are so many tags that they wrap to a second line, which is desired behavior. However, this means that there is a pipe element remaining at the end of the first line or the beginning of the second line (depending on the width of the last tag on the first row), i.e

**Actual Behavior**

```
[  TAG 1  ] | [  TAG 2  ] | [  TAG 3  ] |
[  TAG 4  ] | [  TAG 5  ] |
```

or

```
[  TAG 1  ] | [  TAG 2  ] | [  TAG 3  ]
| [  TAG 4  ] | [  TAG 5  ] |
```

This second example is especially irritating because of the misaligned tags at the start of each line

**Desired Behavior**

```
[  TAG 1  ] | [  TAG 2  ] | [  TAG 3  ]
[  TAG 4  ] | [  TAG 5  ] |
```

How best to achieve this. Logically, I could iterate through the tag elements using JS and if the Y position of one tag differs from the preceeding tag, I would remove the tag's preceeding pipe.

Is there any other faster and less manual way? Thanks.

Comment: As it is dependant on the rendering, you can only add them all and where they wrap (height change as you thought) remove the pipes. You also need to put pipes back when it unwraps too though (and that may cause it to wrap again, so you may need to check for adds, then check for removals... which may cause adds!). Bit of a horrible situation really as you will need to also add line breaks where you remove pipes to avoid the previous problem :)

Comment: Note: A tag, as you show them, could wrap across 2 lines unless you style them to not allow white-space breaks.

Comment: What about using [CSS3 multi-column](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)  >> [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x0b863ew/) ?  Here other [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5ounv84q/3/)  to show than ordering is set vertically

Comment: @A.Wolff: That's pretty cool. What's the compatibility like?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn but your solution keeps relevant ordering and is really more customizable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is dependant on the rendering, you can only add them all and where they wrap (height change as you thought) remove the pipes.

You also need to put pipes back when it unwraps too though. You will need to also add line breaks where you remove pipes to avoid problems.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var pipe = '<span class="pipe"> | </span>';
  var y = 0;
  $('.tag').each(function() {
    var $tag = $(this);
    $tag.prev('.br').replaceWith(pipe);
    var top = $tag.offset().top;
    if (top > y) {
      y = top;
      // Remove any previous pipe as we are on a new line
      // Replace it with a line break
      $tag.prev('.pipe').replaceWith('<br class="br"/>');
    }
  }).last().next('.pipe').remove();
}).resize();
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/5ounv84q/2/

**You can resize the page to see the effect.**

Note: A tag, as you show them, could wrap across 2 lines unless you style them to not allow white-space breaks.

```
.tag {
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    var lastElement = false;
    $(".elt").each(function() {
        if (lastElement && lastElement.offset().top != $(this).offset().top) {
            $(lastElement).next().addClass("no-separator");
        }
        lastElement = $(this);
    });
});
```

```css
.elt,
.separator {
    display: inline-block;
}
.elt {
    width: 200px;
    background-color:red;
}
.no-separator {
    display: none;
    /*Or (depenmding on what you want) : visibility: hidden;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elt">1</div>
<div class="separator"> | </div>
<div class="elt">2</div>
<div class="separator"> | </div>
<div class="elt">3</div>
<div class="separator"> | </div>
<div class="elt">4</div>
<div class="separator"> | </div>
<div class="elt">5</div>
<div class="separator"> | </div>
```

Comment: Display `none` could change the wrapping. Perhaps `hidden` instead?